# serial programming in vc++ mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, serial-port, serial-communication

I am writing two applications one is continuosly listening to "COM3" port and printing data.

When i run other application which should write to that "COM3" port i am getting error serial port does not exist for writing.

can 2 applications open handle to access the same serial COM port in our system at the time

Comment: What are the parameters that you passed to CreateFile when opening the serial port?

Comment: hSerial=CreateFile("COM3",GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
this is my statement to createfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, Windows doesn't allow a serial port to be shared between processes.  Once one process opens a port, another will get error 5 (access denied) when it tries to open the same port.  Serial ports are far too primitive to allow any kind of sharing protocol.

You need a null modem.  Either in hardware by using two ports, connect RxD to Txd.  Or in software, a device driver that emulates serial ports.  Like [this one](http://www.virtual-null-modem.com/).

Comment: Thnx for your reply...i am searching over the web for the past 2 hrs.